# Change location of Navigation Bar

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

When using the Navigation Controller it creates a new Navigation Bar on my first view controller. Intead of that bar being at the top of my screen I would like it to be on bottom. Is this possible? If not can I switch to using a different Nav Bar?

Comment: You need to implement your own if you want to mimic a UINavigationBar in different location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Navigation Bars are always at the top of view controllers, and cannot be moved. You could explore a TabBar or ToolBar though, depending on what you want.

Answer (score 0):

`Navigation Bar` **always appear on the top** of your `UIViewController` when embedded in a `UINavigationController`. You cannot move it to any other position.

Still if you want to achieve such a requirement,

1. Hide the default `UINavigationBar`

   ```
   self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = true
   ```
2. Create a custom `UIView` of same height(44) as the `UINavigationBar` and pin it to the bottom of your controller.